# Swift optional type issue

Tags: ios, swift

so I'm new at swift and iOS programming. I'm trying to record the accelerometer and gyroscope date and display this on screen. With some tutorials I managed to finish my code and kind of understand the code. 
But I keep getting errors. And If I follow the suggestion that xcode gives me I only get more errors..

So this is my code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreMotion

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    //instance variables

    var currentMaxAccelX: Double = 0.0
    var currentMaxAccelY: Double = 0.0
    var currentMaxAccelZ: Double = 0.0

    var currentMaxRotX: Double = 0.0
    var currentMaxRotY: Double = 0.0
    var currentMaxRotZ: Double = 0.0

    var motionManager = CMMotionManager()


    //outlets

    @IBOutlet var accX: UILabel?
    @IBOutlet var accY: UILabel?
    @IBOutlet var accZ: UILabel?
    @IBOutlet var maxAccX: UILabel?
    @IBOutlet var maxAccY: UILabel?
    @IBOutlet var maxAccZ: UILabel?
    @IBOutlet var rotX: UILabel?
    @IBOutlet var rotY: UILabel?
    @IBOutlet var rotZ: UILabel?
    @IBOutlet var maxRotX: UILabel?
    @IBOutlet var maxRotY: UILabel?
    @IBOutlet var maxRotZ: UILabel?

    //functions

    @IBAction func resetMaxValues() {
        currentMaxAccelX = 0
        currentMaxAccelY = 0
        currentMaxAccelZ = 0

        currentMaxRotX = 0
        currentMaxRotY = 0
        currentMaxRotZ = 0
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        self.resetMaxValues()

        motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 0.2
        motionManager.gyroUpdateInterval = 0.2

        //start recording data

        motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.currentQueue(), withHandler: {(accelerometerData: CMAccelerometerData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            self.outputAccelerometerData(accelerometerData.acceleration)
            if (error != nil) {
                print("\(error)")
            }
        })

        motionManager.startGyroUpdatesToQueue((NSOperationQueue.currentQueue()), withHandler: {(gyroData: CMGyroData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            self.outputRotationData(gyroData.rotationRate)
            if (error! = nil) {
                print("\(error)")
            }
        })

        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    func outputAccelerometerData(acceleration: CMAcceleration) {

        accX?.text = "\(acceleration.x).2fg"

        if fabs(acceleration.x) > fabs(currentMaxAccelX) {
            currentMaxAccelX = acceleration.x
        }

        accY?.text = "\(acceleration.y).2fg"

        if fabs(acceleration.y) > fabs(currentMaxAccelY) {
            currentMaxAccelY = acceleration.y
        }

        accZ?.text = "\(acceleration.z).2fg"

        if fabs(acceleration.z) > fabs(currentMaxAccelZ) {
            currentMaxAccelZ = acceleration.z
        }

        maxAccX?.text = "\(currentMaxAccelX) .2f"
        maxAccY?.text = "\(currentMaxAccelY) .2f"
        maxAccZ?.text = "\(currentMaxAccelZ) .2f"

    }

    func outputRotationData(rotation: CMRotationRate) {

        rotX?.text = "\(rotation.x).2fr/s"

        if fabs(rotation.x) > fabs(currentMaxRotX) {
            currentMaxRotX = rotation.x
        }

        rotY?.text = "\(rotation.y).2fr/s"

        if fabs(rotation.y) > fabs(currentMaxRotY) {
            currentMaxRotY = rotation.y
        }

        rotZ?.text = "\(rotation.z).2fr/s"

        if fabs(rotation.z) > fabs(currentMaxRotZ) {
            currentMaxRotZ = rotation.z
        }



    }



    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



}
```

And this is the error that I keep getting where I want to start recording data; Value of optional type 'NSOperationQueue?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use "!" or "?"?

Sorry if this is a stupid question but I really want to understand this stuff!

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Since `NSOperationQueue` is optional, you need force unwrap it using `!`.

So, replace your `NSOperationQueue.currentQueue()` with `NSOperationQueue.currentQueue()!`.

You can go through this [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html) and this [blog](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/understanding-optionals-swift) for understanding Swift optionals.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is

```
NSOperationQueue.currentQueue()
```

Returns an optional value (Refer [NSOperationQueue Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSOperationQueue/currentQueue)). But the,

```
startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:withHandler:
startGyroUpdatesToQueue: withHandler:
```

expects an unwrapped `NSOperationQueue` object (Refer : [CMMotionManager Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMMotionManager_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CMMotionManager/)), but in your code you are passing an optional value, that's the reason why you are getting those errors.

For fixing it change those method calls to:

```
motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.currentQueue()!, withHandler: {(accelerometerData: CMAccelerometerData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
{
})

motionManager.startGyroUpdatesToQueue((NSOperationQueue.currentQueue()!), withHandler: {(gyroData: CMGyroData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
{
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I have replaced the method calls, but then I got 2 errors, both saying that there was use of an unresolved identifier; accelerometerData and gyroData. So I declared those two by writing var gyroData = 0. So those errors disappeared. Now I get 2 errors saying "extra argument "withHandler" in call".

Comment: @Steven: There was a typo in the code, I've fixed it, please try now

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I still keep getting errors. Maybe my xcode is buggy. But now I'm getting the following errors "Expected ',' seperator" and "Expected expression in list of expressions".. The errors are both pointing to the "->". I changed my methods to your suggestion and I've put "self.outputAccelerometerData(accelerometerData.acceleration)" in between the '{}'. I'm sorry that I keep bothering you! I really appreciate your help!